# Editing some values from a file config.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to edit some values from a file config.yml?

config.yml

```
default_params: &defaults
  inform_about_completion:
    first_reminder_day: 5
    second_reminder_day: 1
production:
  <<: *defaults
development:
  <<: *defaults
```

How through the interface to edit two values: `first_reminder_day`, `second_reminder_day`.

I created controller:

```
class Admin::SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def edit   
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :settings, only: [:edit, :update]
end
```

Is it possible to implement it?

Comment: If you change values in a configuration file, Rails has to restart to pick up those changes. This would make it impractical to edit these settings through a webinterface. Better put those user configuration settings in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your `edit` action needs to present the user with a form to edit the configuration parameters. The `update` action needs to do the actual update.

Of course it can be implemented.

** Update **

You have to define correct your routes in `routes.rb` file.

Try this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resource :settings, :only => [:edit, :update]
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried the link to edit the settings. `= link_to _('Settings'), edit_admin_setting_path` and got the error `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=> ' admin/settings"} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: @user3458697 You need to use `resource` and not `resources`. Also, on the command line try to do `rake routes` and see what routes are defined. Do you get the routes that you expect?

Comment: what you need). And what about the controller?